# Tell babel to transpile down to NodeJS

Tags: babeljs, aws-lambda-layers

I use typescript and I'm building a lambda layer but lambda layer seem to be strict with `module.exports.myHelperFunction` rather than `exports.myHelperFunction`, the later doesn't work when you try to import it, it will fail.

So What I want is if I have the following code:

```js
export function myHelperUtility () {
  let a = {};
  return { ...a };
}
```

it should transpile to:

```js
"use strict";

function myHelperUtility () {
  let a = {};
  return { ...a };
}

module.exports.myHelperUtility = myHelperUtility;
```

Rather than:

```js
"use strict";

exports.__esModule = true;
exports.test = test;

function test() {
  let a = {};
  return { ...a };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to make it work, instead of using `@babel/preset-env`, I completely removed it and used `@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs` with the following options:

```js
{
  strict: true,
  loose: true,
  importInterop: 'node'
}
```

which did not produce what I wanted to achieve BUT since it removes the `__esmodule` and `_interoprequiredefault`, it will work!